# How to convert a vector of numbers (100x1) into a vector of 0's and 1's of the same dimension?

Tags: matlab, vector

Let's say we have a vector of numbers having dimension 100x1 and having values such as X'= [0.93 0.45 0.36 0.88 .................]. I would like to convert it into a 100x1 vector of 0's and 1's based on a threshold such that any number greater than or equal 0.5 is replaced by 1 and a number less than 0.5 is replaced by 0. The vector of 0's and 1's should look something like this A'=[1 0 0 1.................]. I would like to do it in the shortest way possible without even using a loop. I want to be able to use the inbuilt libraries of matlab for this purpose. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Bin_matrix=Input_matrix>=threshold_value

Comment: how does that make sense ?

Comment: Well, it did work. But how ?

Comment: Thank You very much !!!! You can convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that Matlab is a high level programming language specialized in matrix operations.

A basic built-in feature is the ability to perform scalar-wise operations on matrices with scalars, and the answer to your question is a good example of this.

One can simply compute

```
A=B>t
```

where `B` is the ouput logical matrix, `A` is the input array (which can be real, complex, integer or logical) and `t` the threshold value to which you want to compare `B`. `=` is the assignment operator, and `>` the relational operator that automatically converts `B>t` to a logical array. `>` can be any other relational operator too, namely `>=`, `==`, `<`, `<=` or `~=`.

Note:
`t` does not have to be a scalar. It can be a matrix of size `m*1`, `1*n` or `m*n` (where `A` is of size `m*n`). `B` will always be of size `m*n`.

Comment: In my code I have done something like this                                            
     ' q = 1./(1+exp(-(X*theta))) ; p(:,1)=q(:,1)>=0.5 '  where p is the output matrix while q is the input matrix.